# Create distinct tuple values for columns in csv and compute average for 3rd column

Tags: python, csv, tuples, average

I have a dataset :

```
string1 string2 rate distance 
A.      C.      1    20
A.      B       2.   30
A.      C.      2.   20
```

There are multiple tuple values for the string1 and string2. I want to find distinct tuple for String1 and String2 and then compute the average of rate/distance for the same. This is just the dummy data and the original data has multiple (10000) for a particular tuple.

So Far I have created the tuples. I am not sure how to merge the tuples and compute the average

```
def read_csv(filepath, has_header=False):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)

        data = list(reader)
        header = None
        if has_header:
            header = data[0]
            data = data[1:]


    file.close()
    return data, header

if __name__ == '__main__':

    outfilepath = "data/outfile12.csv"

    outdata = []

    codes, header = read_csv("data/sample.csv", has_header=TRUE)

    # create dictionary
    codes_dict = {

}
        for code in codes:
            codes_dict[(code[0], code[1])]

        for row in codes : 

        #Write logic here
```

The output should look like :

```
string1 string2 column 
    A      C      0.003    
    A      B     0.00030
    B      A    0.000020
```

Can anyone help with the same.

Comment: how you calculate the final result? post a equation

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Final output is dist(string1, string2) , column (which is computed on the average(rate/distance) of all the multiple values for tuple(string1, string2)

Comment: then for posted data set (A,C) result should by 0.075?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Yes, that's the dummy values that I added... my apologies, yes it should be 0.075

Answer (score 2):

Here You go:

=^..^=

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# create raw data
raw_data = StringIO("""
string1 string2 rate distance
A. C. 1 20
A. B 2. 30
A. C. 2. 20""")

# load data into data frame
df = pd.read_csv(raw_data, sep=' ')
# calculate divide
df['divide'] = df['rate'] / df['distance']
# drop not needed columns
df = df.drop(columns=['rate','distance'])
# grop by columns and sum values
result = df.groupby(['string1', 'string2']).mean()
```

Output:

```
string1 string2          
A.      B        0.066667
        C.       0.075000
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. I was quite confused by the groupby function. Was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using `pandas` for these tasks. Google docs youself for particular cases (line no headers in csv file), I'll give a basic example:

```
import pandas as pd
```

First you load the csv and it really depends on its format so might want change separator, I took the csv formatting from your sample data (multiple whitespaces):

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='\s+')
```

Then you group the data by set of columns:

```
groupby = dataframe.groupby(['string1','string2'])
print(groupby.groups)
```

That returns a "DataFrameGroupBy" object that is essentially a list of (tuple of column values, dataframe of rows matching that data) in a wrapper.

Then you apply a custom function to those rows to make a new row:

```
def add_average_velocity(input_rows):
    input_rows['avg_velocity'] = (input_rows['rate']/input_rows['distance']).mean()
    return input_rows

new_dataframe = dataframe.groupby(['string1','string2']).apply(add_average_velocity).reset_index()
print(new_dataframe)
```

Or if you want to completely get rid of all old data and only keep the new:

```
def add_average_velocity(input_rows):
    output_data = pd.Series({'velocity':(input_rows['rate']/input_rows['distance']).mean()})
    # you can skip making a pd.Series objects if you are okay with having the data unnamed in resulting dataframe. You can always rename columns later anyway.
    return output_data

new_dataframe = dataframe.groupby(['string1','string2']).apply(add_average_velocity).reset_index()
print(new_dataframe)
```